# how to pass arguments to falcon.before hook?

Tags: python, falconframework

I need to authorize user based on some rols, so I need to:

```
class Things:
    @falcon.before(myfunc, 'can_delete_tag')
    @on_get(req, resp):
        ...
```

but it seems impossible... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using internal falcon hooks is impossible unless we patch the functionality of falcon. Because hooks in falcon [do not accept](https://github.com/racker/falcon/blob/master/falcon/hooks.py#L23) any parameters at all. But a standard decorator can do that:

```
def Authorize(action):
    def request_checked(func):
        def _f(self, req, resp, *args, **kw):
            u = getUserInfoFromSession(req)
            if isAuthorizedTo(u.get('id'), action):
                return func(self, req, resp, *args, **kw)
            else:
                raise falcon.HTTPUnauthorized('Not Authorized', 'Permission Denied')
        return _f
    return request_checked
```

and now we can use it:

```
class Things:
    @Authorize('can_delete_tag')
    @on_get(req, resp):
        ...
```

Comment: Warning: It's kind of old post now.  Falcon 0.4.0 changed it's internals and this code may not work.  I used this code with falcon 0.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Falcon 1.3 seems to have the same restriction! Heres a work-around

```
import falcon


class HasPermission(object):
    def __init__(self, role_name):
        self.role_name = role_name

    def validate_has_role(self, req, resp, resource, params):
        raise falcon.HTTPBadRequest('Bad request')
```

and to use it.....

```
class Things:
    @Authorize('can_delete_tag')
@on_get(req, resp):
    ...

write_access = HasPermission("WRITE").validate_has_role
read_access = HasPermission("READ").validate_has_role
```

Comment: Note that if you rename validate_has_role() to  __call__(), you can pass the object directly to @before.

Comment: Another option is to use functools.partial().